# How to define a start controller inside my Tabbarcontroller

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

How can I start my Iphone App (Tabbarcontroller) always on the same Viewcontroller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the first view controller will always be the default (and view controllers will  appear on the tab bar in the order added, etc.)

However, you can select a different view controller via the `selectedViewController` property of the [UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. (You can also use the `selectedIndex` property to select a view controller by index numerically.)

**UPDATE**

Incidentally, if you want to force the application to quit (rather than allow it to go into the background) add the "Application does not run in background" option to your application's plist file and set it to true. That said, the current behaviour is correct.

Comment: 0
 
down vote 
accept  What do I wrong, when I exit the app in any of the viewcontrollers and when I restart it, it stays again in the same viewcontroller. I want that I can leave the app and when I come back it stays again in the first Viewcontroller and all the data of the whole app is cleared. Thanks in advance Greetings

Comment: @MarcoA - I suspect you're app is still running in the background. If you double click the home button does it appear at the bottom? (If so, you can hold your finger down on the app and then tap the minus button to close the app.)

Comment: No it does not appear at the bottom.

Comment: @MarcoA In that case, you must have written code that saves/restores the state, which sounds unlikely. If you turn the iPhone/Pod off and on, does it start normally? (If so, it must have been lurking in the background somewhere.)

Comment: Thanks, but the problem I have is that I not want to store state. I always want to delete every state and the app should start from the scratch (default tabbarcontroller)

Comment: @MarcoA By default it will start from scratch, unless you've added code to make it behave otherwise. As such, I suspect your device needs a restart.

Comment: I don't know. It keeps the current state and when I press the home button and restart the App it will go back to this state. I want a restart of the app all the time I start the app.

Comment: @MarcoA Does it keep the state when you restart the iPhone/Pod?

Comment: No it will start the way I want

Comment: @MarcoA In that case, you're not quitting the application - merely putting it into the background. This isn't a coding issue. Read http://www.tuaw.com/2010/06/30/iphone-101-quitting-apps-in-ios-4/ for more information.

Comment: @MarcoA - I've also updated my answer if you don't want your app to background.

Comment: @middaparka- Thanks for your help! I will check that tomorrow and let you know if it will work

Comment: @MarcoA - No problem. If it works, please mark my answer as correct using the grey tick to the left of the answer text. Thanks.